# Node.js: Mongoose dynamic update of player

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code that works. But I would like it to be more dynamic and instead of "mPlayers.0" I would like it to be "mPlayers.counter" so that I can have one single query. It doesn't seem to be a very hard thing to do but I just cant get it to work.

Any help is appreciated!

```
if(counter === 0) {
  models.GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({_id: game._id}, {$set: {"mPlayers.0": updatedPlayer}}).exec();
} else if(counter === 1) {
  models.GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({_id: game._id}, {$set: {"mPlayers.1": updatedPlayer}}).exec();
} else if(counter === 2) {
  models.GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({_id: game._id}, {$set: {"mPlayers.2": updatedPlayer}}).exec();
} else if(counter === 3) {
  models.GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({_id: game._id}, {$set: {"mPlayers.3": updatedPlayer}}).exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you want this:

```
var value = {};
value['mPlayers.' + counter] = updatedPlayer;
models.GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({_id: game._id}, {$set: value}).exec();
```